# Unity3d FireBase SDK after updating - not find compatible versions error on iOs

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, cocoapods

After updating FireBase SDK in project I get error:

iOS framework addition failed due to a CocoaPods installation failure. This will will likely result in an non-functional Xcode project.

After the failure, "pod repo update" was executed and succeeded. "pod install" was then attempted again, and still failed. This may be due to a broken CocoaPods installation. See: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html for potential solutions.

pod install output:

Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Core":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Analytics (= 5.5.0) was resolved to 5.5.0, which depends on
      Firebase/Core (= 5.5.0)

```
Firebase/Core (= 5.4.0)
```

Specs satisfying the Firebase/Core (= 5.4.0), Firebase/Core (= 5.5.0) dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Unity SDK on site is 5.2.1 :(

Any help needed :)

Comment: What are the contents of your Podfile? It looks like its asking for incompatible pod versions.

Comment: Pod file:

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'Unity-iPhone' do

pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '5.5.0'

pod 'Firebase/Auth', '5.5.0'

pod 'Firebase/Core', '5.4.0'

pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '5.5.0'

pod 'FirebaseInstanceID', '3.1.1'

end

Answer (score 0):

It is not valid in CocoaPods to request subspecs from two different versions of the same pod. You're Podfile is requesting `5.4.0` for the Core subspec from the Firebase pod and `5.5.0` for the other Firebase subspecs.

The most minimal solution is to change the Core version reference:

`pod 'Firebase/Core', '5.5.0'`.

However, would be better to remove the version specifications completely to specify the latest supported versions of everything - unless you have special needs to use old versions.